# Marshal.StructureToPtr <-> PtrToStructure rounds DateTime field

Tags: c#, .net, marshalling

The structure

```
public struct Tick : IEquatable<Tick>
{
    public DateTime date;
    public decimal price;
    public int volume;

    public Tick(DateTime date, decimal price, int volume)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.price = price;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = (Tick)obj;
        return this.date == other.date && this.price == other.price && this.volume == other.volume;
    }
    public bool Equals(Tick other)
    {
        return this.date == other.date && this.price == other.price && this.volume == other.volume;
    }
}
```

is changed in this test:

```
    [Test]
    public void MarshalDoesntRoundsDateTime() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var now = new Tick(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(i), i, i);
            var now2 = now;

            var ticks = new Tick[1];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (Tick* ptr = &ticks[0])
                {
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(now2, (IntPtr)ptr, false);
                    now2 = (Tick)Marshal.PtrToStructure((IntPtr)ptr, typeof(Tick));
                    Assert.AreEqual(now.date.Ticks, now2.date.Ticks);
                }
            }
        }
    }


  Expected: 635719676058860752
  But was:  635719676058860000
```

What is going on? Why DateTime is rounded after marshalling? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: Why on earth are you overriding equality for that struct? The *default* behaviour for structs is to compare their fields.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever that was a sanity check because I couldn't understand why they are not equal until I looked into ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marshal.StructureToPtr() is intended to marshal data for unmanaged code.  There is are multiple "standards" for dates in native code, none that are close in range and accuracy to DateTime.  The CLR designers went for the COM interop standard, also exposed by DateTime.ToOADate().

As you can tell from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,42c44d3ff0f33419), it can be no more accurate than 1 msec.  DateTime is accurate to 0.1 usec.  Inevitably the last 4 digits you are looking at must be 0.

It is not clear why you are doing this or why it matters.  Guessing, do keep in mind that Marshal.StructureToPtr() only *seems* like an attractive way to serialize .NET data.

Comment: Thank you! I am using native compressor and need a pointer to an array of structs. My (wrong) assumption was that `StructureToPtr` doesn't change any bit representation and does the same thing as `fixed (Tick* ptr = &ticks[0])`. In a generic method I have a fallback for all unaccounted explicitly types that do not throw on `Marshal.SizeOf` and then I construct a byte[] array using `StructureToPtr`

Answer (score 1):

The true error is that `DateTime` shouldn't be marshalable... If you try to `Marshal` it directly you get an `ArgumentException`.

If you really really want to `Marshal` a `DateTime` (and I don't even want to know why, considering it is a semi-proprietary format of .NET), you could:

```
public long date;

public DateTime Date
{
    get
    {
        return DateTime.FromBinary(date);
    }

    set
    {
        date = value.ToBinary();
    }
}
```

Comment: DateTime has a single `long` field, it is a big PITA that it is not blittable

Comment: @V.B. Life is not about what you want :-) But yes, it is a PITA.

Comment: Your solution is nice and solves the problem. Cannot accept both answers, though. Hans answered what the hell is going on.